# Database Schema: How the relationship can be designed between user, file and folder?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I was wondering how the database schema of Dropbox would be designed? I am thinking about three tables: User, File, Folder with following constraints.

Constraints:

1. A user can contain multiple files and folders.
2. Each file can be shared among multiple users.
3. A file can be organized in folder for one user but not for another user(if the file is shared).
4. Each folder can contain multiple files as well as other folders.

How would you create a relationship between them?

Comment: 1) create a junction table that contains user_id, file_id, folder_id as fk. file_id and folder_id can be null. That way we can find all files for a user and whether they are contained in any folder. Also all files for a given folder (of a user) can be found.

Comment: 2) Since folder has a one-to-many relationship with itself, we can create the folder table with a folder_id column which will be a fk representing the pk of its parent folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ERD fits the rules you've described:

[image: ERD]

Note that in this schema, every user has their own individualized view of folders.  Files, on the other hand, are represented only once but can be assigned to one or more folders, even for different users.

---

**EDIT:** (slightly) expanded model:

With the addition of a single table to track physical folders and their contents, my proposed schema also addresses all of the additional functionality suggested by Branko Dimitrijevic:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sorry, but there seems to be one doubt that I cant get out of my head. What if a file is not present in any folder but directly at root level. So how can we understand for which user the file exists? I apologize in advance if I may have miss something. Also it would be much appreciated if you can elaborate on the diagram.

Comment: There are some more doubts about the schema: 1) Why do we require a self 1-M relationship for physical folder, as the same can be derived using the virtual folder(I mean thats the whole point of junction table)? 2) Why a 1-M relationship is required between physical file and physical folder?

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul The first design is nice and simple and may actually be what you need. Essentially, each user has its own private folder tree, but files can be shared by more than one folder (and therefore more than one user).

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul Also (regarding first design), consider reversing the "orientation" of connection between FOLDER and USER, to avoid "mixing" different users in the same folder tree. This way, only one ("root") folder would be connected to the user, an the ownership would be ascertained by recursively finding the root folder. The original design is not incorrect, we are simply talking about different tradeoffs: ease of querying vs. ease of updating and storage saving. Frankly, I'd probably go with the original design, but with a CHECK constraints to ensure there is no user mixing.

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul As for the second design, I'm not quite sure I understand it ;) It seems a bit too "open" and "loose", so perhaps Joel Brown could comment?

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul As for file existing outside a folder, this can be easily solved by introducing a convention that file must be in _some_ folder, be it a "real" (named) folder or a "root" (unnamed) folder. There is no good way to actually enforce that in the DBMS when using M:N relationships (as were used in mine and Joel's models), so this is something to be done at the application level. On the flip-side, it makes it easy to implement a "Recycle Bin" - don't delete file, just disconnect it from folder. To restore the file, reconnect it to folder.

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul - Regarding Branko Dimitrijevic's comments above.  (i) There is absolutely nothing in the first design that prevents files from being shared by multiple users - which is one of your design goals.  (ii) Flipping the relationship between FOLDER and USER and connecting to only the root folder won't prevent multiple users from sharing folders.  You need application logic to enforce this.  (iii) The original and the second designs are identical except that the 2nd design explicitly acknowledges the physical location of files in addition to tracking each user's view of these files.

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul - File ownership, and all other file access rights (i.e. read/write/delete) can be tracked in the FILE_RIGHTS (1st schema) / VIRTUAL_FILE (2nd schema) table along with what the user's individualized view of the file name and file location are.  This is more flexible than having an extra FK to USER for "file owner", since it allows for shared ownership plus more granularity in the rights being tracked.

Comment: I am sorry, but there is something I would like to be clarified about. The tables VirtualFolder and VirtualFile are just joining tables(but storing additional information about the link), I guess. So should I have a surrogate auto-generated primary key on them. Also I am using an MVC architecture, so should I represent them as Model? Please correct me if I am wrong. Also if possible can you provide me with the basic attributes that would go in these tables?

Comment: The attributes of VirtualFolder and VirtualFile would be anything you want to know about the User's view of folders and files (which is not inherited from the physical copies).  Therefore if you all users to customize the names of folders or files or if you have a different virtual folder structure per user, then these would go here.  Also if you need permission attribution such as owner, read, and write flags, this is where to keep them.  For MVC, these tables would definitely be represented in your model.  They would be just as important (if not more so) than your physical objects.

Comment: @JoelBrown I read an article which describes these links as entity since it contains information about the association. I think that is what your answer says too. Also, since these are entities they must be mapped to model. I am guessing they would need their own primary key (surrogate) for their identification as well. Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: @JoelBrown Request for a pro tip: If I am storing files  in file system, how should I store the path? My storage technique is somewhat like this: /user_id(as root folder name)/folder_name/sub_folder_name/file_name. So should I store the whole path or just relative path. Also I am storing folder path too. Is this a good idea? I think my solution is very far from elegant, so I will research on it. But I would like your perspective on it, since you have clear understanding on my requirements. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul - It is a matter of debate/religious war whether intersection entities should have a surrogate key.  The two best reasons for adding a surrogate key to an intersection entity are that (i) there are child entities which need to FK to the intersection or (ii) you have a philosophical reason for always having surrogate keys.  Since virtual folder points to itself, this qualifies as situation (i).

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul - For how to store you file names, the most normalized form would not repeat path in the file name.  This lets you change the names of parent folders without risking an inconsistency with your folders.  This may make it harder to read the data out, so you could decide to keep redundant path information in your file names.  However, if you do this, you have to be very carefull to manage that redundancy in your code to make sure things stay synchronized.  This isn't easy and it's not fool-proof, so be careful if that's the way you choose to go.

Answer (score 5):

The [Joel Brown's model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737474/533120) is a good start, but let me tickle your imagination with another possibility:

[image]

This model has the following properties:

- It emulates file system *hard links*. You can have a single file in multiple folders or even multiple times in the same folder, under different names. Ditto for folders.
- It separates naming from content, which is necessary for the "hard links" paradigm. So, names are in FILE_IN_FOLDER and FOLDER_IN_FOLDER (instead of in FILE and FOLDER).
- It properly enforces the "local" name uniqueness (you can't have two files or folders named the same way under the same parent folder).
- A user owns neither files nor folders. User just owns links. This way, each user has **her own private "directory tree"**, potentially sharing all files, or none or anything in between.

The question, of course, is whether the increased flexibility you get with this model is worth the extra complexity, but this is something only you can answer...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried a basic implementation for this schema in MSSQL Server. Honestly, it was very intellectually stimulating to understand your design and how it conforms to all the constraints. But there is a doubt: "A user owns neither files nor folders." What if we wanted to know who the owner of a file is? Considering that we can allow some access rules to other shared users. How to differentiate between users and other shared users? My thoughts were to create a owner_id as fk in file(as well as folder) table which creates a one-to-many relationship between file and user.

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul Yes, you can certainly create a FK between FILE and USER to mark one of the users as being "special" (i.e. file owner). The question is, do you actually need this? I.e. should all users sharing the same file be treated equally or not? Again, only you can answer that...

Comment: Thanks for it clearing it up. I think it pretty much completes the constraints. This may sound an odd request but can you help me understand Joel's design and how it is different from yours. Also there are some doubts about it. Can you please help me clear them up? Once again thanks for all the learning experience.

Comment: I also use this schema and I have a question: Consider the following structure: Folder > Subfolder > Subsubfolder. So when I want to share the whole folder with another user I have to copy all 3 "Folder_in_Folder" rows and assign them to the other user right?

Comment: @Manu Yes, in this schema user must explicitly own the desired (sub)set of links, each represented by a separate row.

Comment: Okay thank you! But I have another problem. When a User is deleting a shared directory, only the link should be deleted but when he deletes a shared directory inside a shared directory then the directory and all subitems should be deleted for all users. (Like Dropbox). So I have to check every time if the parent folder is shared. Do you have a better solution or idea?

Comment: @Manu Well, I guess it depends on whether the delete should be "private" or "public". If private, only links belonging to that user should be removed, but other users can still access the object.

Comment: Ok so I have to implement application logic for that. Thank you very much for your help!